# How to random sign like that?

Tags: php, random

How to random sign like that ?

```
echo Rand(|,★,●,-);
```

When i test this code it's will show error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '|', expecting ')'
```

Comment: at the very least you'll need some quotation marks...

Comment: Put your random symbols in an array, shuffle and then display entry 0

Comment: @Alnitak that's wrong, even with quotation marks, Rand does not function like that in PHP.

Comment: @olive_tree So you expect those characters to appear as literal tokens and not as strings, then?

Comment: @Alnitak I'm talking about the Rand fn, it only expects integer input.

Comment: @olive_tree note what I said: "_at the very least_".  I made no comment about `rand`, not least because the OP is calling `Rand()` and not `rand()` so I made no assumptions about the arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store the signs in an array and use [`array_rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) to select a random item:

```
$signs = array('|', '★', '●', '-');
$random = $signs[array_rand($signs)];

echo $random;
```

Comment: Make sure the file is saved with UTF-8 encoding.

Answer (score 1):

PHPs `rand()` needs a range defined by two `int` values. So a valid call would be  `rand(0,5)`. If you need a random char from predefined string you can do this:

```
$str = '|★●-';
echo $str{rand(0,strlen($str)-1)};
```

Comment: it's ok , but my site cannot show ★ my site use `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`

Comment: Strange that this doesn't work seems as the encoding is missed after selecting the char from string. Then you have to do the array-version Gergo Erdosi suggested.

Answer (score 0):

From the PHP docs:

> rand — Generate a random integer

So what you can do is randomize an integer, that can serve as the index for an array that contains the signs you want.

Comment: right, and that array of signs _will have quotation marks around the signs!_

Answer (score 0):

The PHP `rand` function takes two numbers and not characters. You should do it like that:

```
// Define a function that takes an array an return
// random element from this array
function getRand($array) {
    $size = count($array);
    $index = rand(0, $size); // random index
    return $array[$index];
}

// And use it like this
echo getRand(array('|','★','●','-'));
```

Note that values are between quotes !