# Access specific characters in UTF-8 string

Tags: php, string, encoding, utf-8

A [questions answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25242135/1652031) leaded me to the following "problem" or challenge:

Is it somehow possible to get a character from a specfic position if the string is UTF-8 encoded and contains special chars.

So for non-special char containing strings this works:

```
$str = 'abcd';
echo $str{1}; // will print "b"
```

But for a string like this:

```
$str = 'abc★';
echo $str{1}; // will return "b"
echo $str{3}; // leads to a question mark
```

Of course the PHP file is encoded in UTF-8 and `<meta charset="utf-8">` is in the head of the HTML.

So is there any solution to get this method of catching a char in the string working?

Answer (score 1):

One possible way

```
$str = 'abc★';

preg_match_all('/./su', $str, $m);
$chars = $m[0];

echo $chars[1]; // b
echo $chars[3]; // ★
```

`/./su` means "any character, including newline ("s"), in utf8 mode ("u")".

Or like this

```
echo mb_substr($str, 3, 1, 'utf8'); // ★
```

Comment: So there is no possibility to get it working with the curly braces?

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER: well, I have a library that allows you to do things like `echo str('abc★')[3]`, which correctly echoes the star. But no way with vanilla php.

Comment: Okay but why does this not works? I mean it's always told that a string is an array of characters. So it should be possible to access one of it without break the character...

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER: no, php string is not an array of _characters_. It's an array of _bytes_, and in the unicode world, char != byte.